# I am having huge problems installing Ralink RT5390 Wi-Fi drivers

Tags: 16.04, command-line, drivers, wireless, ralink

I have read many articles and nothing really helped. I am running UBUNTU 16.04.

For 2 days I've tried to install my Wi-Fi driver(Ralink RT5390) for my HP Pavilion dv7 and havent accomplished anything yet, except for the fact that I've accomplished to enable the button "enable wi-fi" on the right top corner of the screen while following some steps for another driver on some forum. However no networks appeared.

Then, I followed some steps from GitHub on how to install the appropriate driver for me and these were the steps:

https://github.com/Inglebard/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2

1. download archive
2. extract content
3. `cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO`
4. copy file patch in `2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO`
5. `patch -p1 < rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` (if asks for directory point it to `pci_main_dev.c`)
6. make sure `/os/linux/config.mk` reads `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y`
7. `make`
8. `sudo make install`
9. `modprobe rt5390sta`

But when it comes to "make" command at step 7, it doesnt seem to work.

Error:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/home/zrobot/Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/zrobot/Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o] Error 1
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/zrobot/Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/zrobot/Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic'
Makefile:375: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

YOUR HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: Too little info. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1011752/edit) question and write comprehensive list of actions and error messages you got. What you are trying to `make`? Where you got its sources and so on?

Comment: @N0rbert here it is the extended explanation of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this module on kernel `4.4.0-116-generic` with the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/Inglebard/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.git
cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2
tar -xjvf 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.tar.bz2.bz2

cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
cp ../patch/rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch .

patch -p1 <rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch
sed -i "s\HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n\HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y\g" os/linux/config.mk

sudo make # sudo is needed because of /tftpboot
sudo make install

sudo modprobe rt5390sta
```

Module was loaded successfully:

```
$ lsmod | grep ^rt
rt5390sta            1441792  0

$ modinfo rt5390sta
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt5390sta.ko
version:        2.6.0.0
srcversion:     30A94311FFD42FD05E12867
alias:          pci:v00001186d00003C05sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00005362sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00005392sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d0000539Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00005390sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00003390sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00003092sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00003091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00003090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           mac:rt28xx: wireless mac addr (charp)
```

But I can't compile it on `4.13.0-36-generic` as you wrote.

Other driver from  https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver does not compile on 4.13 too.